# Clarify an answer without the ability to comment

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, answers

I am refering to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24224905/2117699) on stackoverflow.

The question is old but has many views, and the accepted answer contains a minor mistake. I wanted to clarify the answer in a comment for potential future viewers, but I do not have enough reputation to comment. Should I do as I just did (i.e. post an answer that will likely be never upvoted) or directly edit the accepted answer?

Please don't tell me I should just "increase my reputation".

**EDIT**
In the end, someone edited the accepted answer to include my clarification and let me delete my answer. I would auto-answer to this question but I need at least 10 reputation for that. Oh well :)

Answer (score 2):

**You should *absolutely not* write a comment in an answer.**

I would think it's largely self-evident that the reputation limitation is there to encourage you to stick around a bit longer and watch how things are done before writing comments, and *not* as a fun little easter egg whereby you are expected to use *anything other than the comment system* to go ahead and post your comments anyway.

The correct approach is to wait until you have enough reputation to post the comment as a comment.

In cases like yours, where you're A Good Guy™, this may seem harsh, but in the general case this restriction is a good thing, and is nothing personal against *you* specifically; anyway, ultimately 50 reputation isn't that hard to get.